# Atom Text Editor: Why did a computer crash wipe the content of my current file and save it? How can I get my code back?

Tags: javascript, git, github, atom-editor

Yesterday, I started using Github's Atom Text Editor, and it has been fantastic, until just now...

My Macbook Pro (OSX 10.9.4) crashed while I was editing a big file in Atom.  After reboot, the file is now completely empty.

This is heartbreaking and hours of work has been lost.

I hadn't committed to git today.  I thought saving was enough.

I've never this problem with Sublime Text. What happened?  Is there any way to get my file back?  Has this happened to anyone else?

Comment: I wasn't able to install Atom on my machine at work because one of the directories it tried to install to makes a file location exceed the maximum number of characters allowed in Windows. It seems a bit buggy to me at times too, alt+f shortcut keeps getting replaced. Visual Studio Code is now out, is absolutely superb and Mac is supported.

Comment: Use Time Machine on the Mac and set it to just before the crash?

Comment: I don't have Time Machine set up.  I haven't had a problem like this for years :\

Comment: That sucks. I would advise to install Local History or Life Archive package for having extra backups.